# Segmentation Fault when running a script using System ()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting a very weird error I can't wrap my head around.

Here is my code, it is very simple, I just call a function in main the calls System()

```
string function1()
{
    cout << "Running my script... " << endl;
    system ("./myscript.sh");
    cout << "Done Running my script... " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "running function"  << endl;
    function1();
    cout <<"done"<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

The script it runs does nothing (to simplify the problem), it just echoes

```
#!/bin/bash
#UnMount Script

echo "HELLO THERE"
```

Thing is, as soon as it exits the Function(), it immediately give a segmentation fault!

This is my output:

```
running function
Running my script... 
HELLO THERE
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm clueless, what is causing this!?

Comment: I want to mention that if I cancel Function() and run system ("./myscript.sh") inside main, it runs smoothly without a segmentation fault

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your `function1` is declared as returning a `string`, but it does not return anything. C++ compiler should have issued a warning about this:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

When your function returns, the caller needs to perform cleanup actions on the string that your function has returned. Since you did not return anything, these actions trigger undefined behavior, eventually leading to a segmentation fault.

Adding a return statement or declaring the function as `void` will fix the problem.

Comment: omg I cant believe I missed that! I’ve been coding for 10 hours straight! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: That's the reason we shouldn't ignore warnings, and possibly turn some of warnings as errors.

Comment: @HadiEsper to avoid things like that in future, compile using `-Wall` option.